# Load files from Amazon S3 from Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, amazon-s3

I have lightning component for working with amazon s3. I generating unsigned url in apex controller and then  try load file using XmlHttpRequest to Amazon.
I added "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com" to CPS Trusted Sites.
And added my sf org in S3 cors:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://my-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

And then from lightning controller try load file:

```
    var loadPdfRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    loadPdfRequest.open('GET', unsignedUrl);
    loadPdfRequest.send();
```

And i fetch:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder_1/myFile.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=MyAccessKey&Expires=1507207939&Signature=Signature.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://my-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

What I am doing wrong? Maybe Locker Service?
My component version is **39.0**

Comment: Have you added this site into trusted sites?

Comment: Yes of course I added

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have added the non-lightning domain in your CORSRule. You should also add the lightning domain.

CORSRule has `<AllowedOrigin>https://my-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com</AllowedOrigin>`

But your lightning page is loaded from a different domain '**https://my-dev-ed.lightning.force.com**'